# How do I change the array Input Order in C

Tags: c, arrays

I need to input five numbers and then a positive or negative.  The order will be changed like the number.

For example, if three (3) is the number then:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

will become:

4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1 2 3

Please do not use pointers.  I have made the following code and would like to be able to improve on it.  Can I use a mathematical formula using the modulus operator `%` ?  If so, how would I be able to do it.

Thanks, this is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define n 10
int main(void)
{
    int num[n] = { 0 }, assist[n] = { 0 }, i = 0, j = 0, variable = 0, k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter index. %d\n", i );
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }
    printf("please enter the circle number\n");
    scanf("%d", &variable);
    printf("\n\n");

    if (variable >= 0)
    {
        for (i = variable, j = 0; i < n; i++, j++)
        {
            assist[j] = num[i];
            k++;
        }

        for (i = 0, j = k; i < variable, j < n; i++, j++)//to assist//
        {                                                          
            assist[j] = num[i];
        }
    }

    if(variable < 0)
    {
        for (i = n + variable, j = 0; i < n; i++, j++)
        {
            assist[j] = num[i];
            k++;
        }
        for (i = 0, j = k; i < n + variable, j < n; i++, j++)
        {
            assist[j] = num[i];
        }
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)//output//
    {
        printf("%d\n", assist[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this code work? If so, this question is off-topic.

Comment: it's work but i need to use it by % and to improve it

Comment: What do you mean with `use it by %`?

Comment: Your code (as posted) does not work.  If your actual code compiles, then what you posted `!=` your actual code.  Fix your post, and show some effort at describing where it is failing.

Comment: @ryyker try it now..

Comment: @meaning-matters mathematical formula with % i think....

Comment: The edit I just made to your post includes the minimum prototype for `main` function ( i.e. `int main(void){... return 0;}` ) along with formatting.  Regarding your need to use the `%` symbol, I assume you need to use it in its form as the _[C modulus operator](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html)_, and not the string formatting token (eg. `"%s"`)?

Comment: @ryyker yes c modulus operator. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. I did not compile; any small mistakes are for you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10

int main(void)
{
    int numbers[N];
    int offset;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    printf("\nplease enter the circle number: ");
    scanf("%d", &offset);
    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", num[(i + offset) % N]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Should there be a return statement somewhere in there?

Comment: @ryyker why?! Hasn't been needed for 18 years. When did you learn your C?

Comment: The declaration promises that some function will return an int. Then ... it doesn't. That is reason for compilers to complain; old and new ones do so. "...it is good programming practice to always use a return statement, even if you don't have to."

Comment: @ryyker in C99 the default return value of `main()` is 0. So no `return` required.